# How do I create a youtube playlist with the Google API node client?

Tags: node.js, youtube, google-api-nodejs-client

Using Google's google-api-nodejs-client (official google node library), I had this piece of code running many months ago. I had left it aside.

```
googleapis.discover('youtube', 'v3').execute(function (err, client) {
    var request = client.youtube.playlists.insert({
         part: 'snippet,status',
         resource: {
             snippet: {
                 title: "hello",
                 description: "description"
             },
             status: {
                 privacyStatus: "private"
             }
          }
     });
    request.withAuthClient(oauth2Client).execute(function (err, res) {...
```

I have restarted the project and downloaded the latest version of the library through npm and now when I run the code above I systematically get the following error object:

```
Object
     code: 400
     errors: Array[1]
         0: Object
             domain: "youtube.playlist"
             message: "Must specify playlist title."
             reason: "playlistTitleRequired"
         length: 1
              length: 1
     message: "Must specify playlist title."
```

Which according to the document and sample seems correct [google sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#create_a_playlist)

I've stepped through the library code, it seems that the request is not being built properly but before reporting it as a possible bug I wanted to ask the hive mind.

Anyone had success using the library recently? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the node library doesn't follow the convention in the api documentation. when calling an api with has request parameters and a body, the parameters are passed in an object as the first parameters of the call, and the body as a separate object as the second parameter of the object.

In my case the request needs to be built as such:

```
var request = client.youtube.playlists.insert(
    { part: 'snippet,status'},
    {
      snippet: {
          title: "hello",
          description: "description"
      },
      status: {
          privacyStatus: "private"
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For insert operation the value of `part` should be `snippet` and/or `status`

```
part: 'snippet,status',
```

For more details check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert).

Comment: that variable is set earlier in the code, i corrected the code in my question.